# MongoDB .NET - Get IMongoCollection by Name

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm refactoring some legacy code away from the `MongoDB.Driver.Legacy` API.

I've got the following method, which gets a `MongoCollection` by string collection name.

```
    protected virtual MongoCollection GetMongoCollection(Type type)
    {
        return Store.GetCollection(GetCollectionName(type));
    }
```

`Store` in this example is a `MongoDatabase` from the Legacy API. The `GetCollectionName()` method looks up various things in BsonClassMap to determine the string name of the collection:

```
    private string GetCollectionName(Type type)
    {
        return !IsRegisteredWithClassMap(type) ? type.Name : GetRegisteredClassMapType(type).Name;
    }

    private Type GetRegisteredClassMapType(Type objectType)
    {
        if (objectType.BaseType == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var isroot = BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(objectType.BaseType).IsRootClass;
        return isroot ? objectType.BaseType : GetRegisteredClassMapType(objectType.BaseType);
    }

    private bool IsRegisteredWithClassMap(Type objectType)
    {
        var isRegistered = GetRegisteredClassMapType(objectType);
        return isRegistered != null;
    }
```

How would I implement the `GetMongoCollection()` method using the new API.  The `IMongoDatabase` from the new API doesn't have a `GetCollection()` method which accepts a string.  Only a Generic version `GetCollection<T>`

Answer (score 2):

If you set a discrimitor to the class (custom collection name), you can use this:

```
[BsonDiscriminator("CollectionName")]
public class MyModel
{ 
...
}

var client = new MongoClient("connection string");
var database = client.GetDatabase("database name");

var collection = database.GetCollection<MyModel>(BsonClassMap.LookupClassMap(typeof(MyModel)).Discriminator)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected virtual MongoCollection GetMongoCollection(Type type)
{
    var method = typeof(IMongoDatabase).GetMethod("GetCollection");
    var result = method.MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(yourMongoDbInstance);
    return (MongoCollection) result;
}
```

if you can afford more effort just change the previous method signature in this way:

```
protected virtual MongoCollection GetMongoCollection<T>() {
   return yourMongoDbInstance.GetCollection<T>();
}
```